# to insert Empty value into Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, csv, liquibase

I am having a postgresql database. I am using liquibase to insert data into the tables in postgresql from CSV files.
Here I have table ABC with column of type SMALLINT.

```
CREATE TABLE ABC (
NAME VARCHAR(20),
REQUIRED SMALLINT DEFAULT 0,
SUMMARY VARCHAR(50)
);
```

My CSV

```
NAME,REQUIRED,SUMMARY
John,,Playing
```

I get the following error

```
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ","n
```

The changeset

```
<changeSet id="12345"
        author="test" runOnChange="true">
         <loadUpdateData
            encoding="UTF-8"
            file="/data/ABC.csv"
            quotchar=""
            separator=","
            tableName="ABC">
        <column name="NAME" type="STRING"/>
        <column name="REQUIRED" type="NUMERIC"/>
        <column name="SUMMARY" type="STRING"/>
    </loadUpdateData>
    </changeSet>
```

Can anyone please help here. Another question is , why is the default not working in this case ?

Comment: Could you try `John,NULL,Playing`

Comment: @PhilippJohannis , its getting stored as [NULL] in the table. Is it fine. With previous database it was empty(blank) field in table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Required` is defined as `smallint` - this means it can be any integer between -32768 and 32767 OR `NULL`.

`NULL`can be inserted by

```
NAME,REQUIRED,SUMMARY
John,NULL,Playing
```

Something like `''` can't be inserted into a int column. I assume `[NULL]` and `empty(blank)` is just a different rendering by different db tools.